# Google Visualization Table: query to change label to multiple columns

Tags: google-api, google-sheets

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=XXXXXX&hl=it_IT&headers=1');
    query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C contains "XXXX" order by C DESC label B "XXXX"');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}
```

This function works fine. What I'd like to do is change another label (together with ColB). I've tried

```
query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G where C contains "XXXX" order by C DESC label B "XXXX" label C "XXXX"');
```

But I get a timeout error. I've tried separating the 2 with a comma (`label B "XXXX", label C "XXXX"`) or an AND (`label B "XXXX" AND label C "XXXX"`) with no luck. How should I format the query in order to change the label to multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

Tested and this works:

```
LABEL B 'Label1', C 'Label2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using the api directly, however the generic syntax definitely works in the following case:

select H, avg(K), avg(L), avg(M), avg(N) group by H label avg(K) 'Food', avg(L) 'Rent', avg(M) 'Healthcare', avg(N) 'Hygiene'

My columns headers (since they are averages) are thus avg(K) etc.

Not a full answer but hopes it at least validate the google query syntax and helps isolate your problem.

(Your question helped my get that syntax right)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but try `label B "XXXX", C "XXXX"`

Comment: Nope.. I'm not getting the timeout error but the column is still labeled the same as the source sheet.

Comment: And it's weird it's not working because that's the formatting suggested here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Label

Comment: Test it. It's not fair to answer with "not sure, but..."